# Getting Initial expression is of incorrect type, expected: String but was: Set<String>

Tags: apex

```
Map<string, set<String>> mapskill_x_SkillGrouplist = new Map<string, set<String>>();
Map<string, String>mapSkill_x_SkillGroup = new Map<string, String>();
Map<string, set<String>> map_TechId_x_SkillGrouplist  = new Map<string, set<String>>();
set<string>   skillGroupName =new set<string>();
//skill logic - fetch skills & skill group for app expertise
   for(SVMX_NBN_Appointment_Expertise__c apt: [Select Name, SVMX_NBN_Skill__c,SVMX_NBN_Skill__r.Name , SVMX_NBN_Skill_Group__c,SVMX_NBN_Skill_Group__r.Name from SVMX_NBN_Appointment_Expertise__c])
   {
      if(mapskill_x_SkillGrouplist.containsKey(apt.SVMX_NBN_Skill__r.Name)){
      mapskill_x_SkillGrouplist.get(apt.SVMX_NBN_Skill__r.Name).add(apt.SVMX_NBN_Skill_Group__r.Name);
   }
    else
    {
      set<String> str = new set<String>{apt.SVMX_NBN_Skill_Group__r.Name};
            
      mapskill_x_SkillGrouplist.put(apt.SVMX_NBN_Skill__r.Name,str);
    }
}
system.debug('mapskill_x_SkillGrouplist'+mapskill_x_SkillGrouplist);


set <id> techIds = new set <id>();
techIds.add('a265P000000JXWTQA4');
techIds.add('a265P000000JT6vQAG');
system.debug('techIds'+techIds);
//fetch skill & tech from tech expertise
for(SVMXC__Service_Group_Skills__c exp : [select id, SVMXC__Skill__r.Name, SVMXC__Group_Member__c, SVMXC__Group_Member__r.Name from SVMXC__Service_Group_Skills__c where SVMXC__Group_Member__c in :techIds])
  {
     skillGroupName= mapskill_x_SkillGrouplist.get(exp.SVMXC__Skill__r.Name);
     if(map_TechId_x_SkillGrouplist.containsKey(exp.SVMXC__Group_Member__c))
     {
        map_TechId_x_SkillGrouplist.get(exp.SVMXC__Group_Member__c).addall(skillGroupName);
     }
     else
     {
        set<String> str = new set<String>{skillGroupName};
        map_TechId_x_SkillGrouplist.put(exp.SVMXC__Group_Member__c, str);
     }
                    
   }
   system.debug('map_TechId_x_SkillGrouplist'+map_TechId_x_SkillGrouplist);
```

Comment: I've rolled back your edit because keeping your original (incorrect) code is important context for the answer(s) that you get. If you feel you _must_ make a change to reflect something from an answer, you should add it as an entirely new "section", so to say.

Answer (score 1):

It is helpful if you identified the line number of the error but I surmise the issue is

```
set<String> str = new set<String>{skillGroupName};
```

`skillGroupName` is declared as `Set<String>` but the syntax

`new Set<String> { ... }` expects to see within the `{ .. }` a list of string variables or constants and you are providing a Set, not a comma-separated list of scalars.

You can simplify this by just doing:

```
Set<String> str = skillGroupName;
```

but since I don't know what the business logic is supposed to be, your fix may be different

*You should also thank the kind members of the Community who reformatted your code to be readable*

Comment: Or, if they want to *duplicate* the set, `skillGroupName.clone()`, etc.

Comment: Line: 29, Column: 1 System.NullPointerException: Argument 1 cannot be null --- 
Getting this error if I change the line Set<String> str = skillGroupName;

Comment: maddy - what is line 29 ... we can't infer this from your current environment